# Inclusion induce an isomorphism

Tags: linear-algebra, modules

I have a small question

If $E,F$ are two sub-modules of a module $G$,

how to prove that the inclusion $E \rightarrow E+F$ induces an isomorphism $(E/E \cap F) \simeq (E + F) / F$

Please

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inclusion $E\to E+F$ induces a map $\phi: E\to (E+F)/F$ given by $x\mapsto x+F$. This defines a homomorphism with kernel $E\cap F$. That is, $$E/E\cap F \cong Im \ \phi.$$

To show $\phi$ is surjective, we let $x+y+F\in (E+F)/F$ where $x\in E$ and $y\in F$. Observe that $x+y+F=x+F$ in $(E+F)/F$ since $y\in F$ and notice that $$\phi(x)=x+F=x+y+F.$$ Thus, $\phi$ is surjective, which completes the proof.

Comment: so you use the first theorem of isomorphism ?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: $E/(E\cap F) \rightarrow (E+F)/F$ is onto (surjectiv) by the fact that $E\rightarrow E+F$ is an inclusion right ??

Comment: $E\to E+F/F$ is surjective. Indeed, let $x+y+F\in (E+F)/F$ where $x\in E$ and $y\in F$. Note that $y=x+y-x\in F$  and hence, $x+y+F=x+F$. That is, $x\mapsto x+y+F$.

Comment: $E \to (E+F)/F$ is onto, so the map $E/(E \cap F) \to (E+F)/F$ given by the first isomorphism theorem is also onto.

Comment: but please why $E\rightarrow (E+F)/F$ is onto please

Comment: @Vrouvrou: My comment above shows this map is onto. A typical element of $(E+F)/F$ is of the form $x+y+F$ with $x\in E$ and $y\in F$ and we showed that $x\mapsto x+F= x+y+F$. Does this help?

Comment: where we use the fact that we have an inclusion $E\rightarrow E+F$ ?

Comment: i'm sorry but i still don't understand how to prove the surjectivity

Comment: @Vrouvrou: I've made an edit to the original answer, hopefully this helps. For showing this is surjective, remember that $u+F=v+F$ in $G/F$ if and only if $u-v\in F$. Hence, in our setting, $y=x+y-x\in F$ and hence, $x+y+F=x+F$.

Comment: thank you for your edit, please it is alwayse true that $E\rightarrow E+F$ induce a map $E\rightarrow (E+F)/F$ ?

Comment: @Vrouvrou: Yes, it's just the composition of the inclusion map with the projection map.

Comment: the projection map is $E+F\rightarrow E+F/F$ right

Comment: @Vrouvrou: Yes. You could also think of it as the restriction of $G\to G/F$ to $E+F$.